# Single electron reduction of ketone by Na or Zn

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, carbonyl-compounds, chemoselectivity

Whenever we add Na or Zn metal to a ketone, why does the electron prefer to attack the carbonyl bond and form a radical, instead of removing the acidic hydrogen and forming an enolate and $\ce{H2}$ gas?

I was thinking that usually when we add Na and there is a sufficiently acidic Hydrogen present, it reacts and releases $\ce{H2}$. I just wanted to know if there is an advantage in attacking the carbonyl bond instead of an acid-base reaction. Also, is this dependent on kinetic or thermodynamic control.

Comment: What are your thoughts? How do you approach this problem?

Comment: Think about the stability of the radical(s) and other species that would form.

Comment: @EashaanGodbole But aren't acid-base reactions quite fast, also K(eq) is more than 10^5

Comment: @Ayushmaan I won't compare radical reactions with acid-base reactions.

Comment: @EashaanGodbole So is there a way to deduce where acid-base or radicle would be preferrable in case of Na?

Comment: Why do you think sodium participates in acid/base chemistry? When it produces hydrogen, that's via single electron transfer. It just happens to be favorable to produce hydrogen radicals.

Comment: @Zhe           Yes, but why. Creating a radicle would break the carbonyl bond permanently while generating a carbanion does not decrease the stability (atleast not permanently)

Comment: I don't think you've considered the mechanism enough. With the carbonyl, you create a radical anion. What does the process for hydrogen abstraction look like? Do you donate an electron to the $\sigma*$ orbital first? What does that species look like? And if it's an $S_{\mathrm{N}}2$ type abstraction as in the answer below, consider how much more unlikely that is compared to the process for just donating an electron to a carbonyl.

Comment: @Zhe           Could you frame it as an answer with the mechanism. I've tried and its not becoming clear to me.

Comment: I don't know what the exact mechanism for the hydrogen atom abstraction would be. Mostly because it is disfavored over what appears to be an easy reduction of the carbonyl group (see the answer below). The accepted mechanism, if studied, is probably available in the literature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the carbonyl compound under consideration be acetone.

Case I: Hydrogen Abstraction

[image: Hydrogen Abstraction]

The species formed are NaH and an allyl-type radical. The resonating system includes an electronegative oxygen atom, which also has an incomplete octet in one of the canonical forms.

In essence, products are not really stable.

Case II: Attack on Carbonyl
[image: Attack on Carbonyl]

The species formed is a radical anion, which are relatively stable as the filled orbital of the oxygen relieves some electron deficiency of the radical. This effect is stronger than the one offered the pi-bond in Case I.

Comment: I would suspect that this is kinetically controlled. So I'm not entirely convinced by an argument based on relative product stability. If I had to take a guess I'd say that it is simply because the electron adds into the LUMO of the carbonyl compound, which is the C=O π* (and not the C–H σ*). But I'm not confident enough to post it as an answer.